# Influence as a verb, can it be followed by ON or OVER

Tags: word-usage

There is a rule which says that influence as a verb shouldn't be followed by any prepositions.

> I influenced her.

But is it always true? Can this be said in real life language?

> I influenced over/on her.

Comment: Why would you think otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

The verb "influence" is transitive.  This means it has a direct object, usually a noun or noun phrase.  So "I influenced on her" is incorrect grammar.

<sub>There is the possibility of using "influence" to mean "to exert your influence" and form a sentence like "I'm going to start influencing on Thursday". That is odd and I don't recommend you use influence like that</sub>